# Charging different batteries with same charger (SkyRC T200)

Tags: battery-charging, charger

I have a SkyRC T200 which is a polyvalent charger (it says it can charge LiPo, LiHV, LiFe, LiIon, NiMH, NiCd, PB)
I can choose the charging voltage and amperage with that charger.

I have batteries to charge, like an electric screwdriver battery, or a car battery. It would be great to have only one charger for multiple devices.

I wonder if I can safely charge these batteries using that charger, given that I built safe connectors between the two (good connection and thick enough depending on amperage).

For example, for the car battery I would use a charging voltage of 12V and a 0.1*Capacity (C) for the amperage (as indicated in the charger manual).

My electric screwdriver battery has 14.4V indicated on it. When I look at the SkyRC manual, it says LiIon nominal cell voltage is at 3.6V. So I guess that the battery has 4 cells (3.6x4=14.4), so I would use the "4S" program for LiIon. For the amperage, I don't know. By researching I find 0.3*Capacity, but I'm not sure. Will it be okay to charge it using the program ?

Are there other things to consider? Like, maybe, stock chargers may have very specific charging patterns?

Thanks!

Comment: If I was a good poker player, I'd guess @vega was advertising this product with a naive question. My bet is It performs as advertised https://www.skyrc.com/t200

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 That's true that I could have said "configurable charger" instead of the exact product. But I wanted to be precise in case if someone knew and used this specific charger. Especially, this charger is made/sold to charge batteries of remote controlled devices, so I was not sure if the batteries for other devices could be different in their conception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally yes, you can safely charge almost all batteries using a configurable charger or even a bench supply if you know what you’re doing.  That said, you can make bad things happen, sometimes spectacular, if you get it wrong.  So for lead-acid you’ll charge at 2.6V per cell and 0.1C, for LiPo you’ll use 4.2V at  0.3C.  Those are maximum figures, so the charger should ensure that neither over-voltage nor over-current can occur.  Some chargers do fancy stuff - for lead acid you can start at a higher current and then reduce to provide a quicker charge cycle, and NiCd chargers (remember them?) often discharge cells before charging to minimise the memory effect.  Some chargers switch to a ‘trickle’ mode once the charge is complete, although if you set the max voltage correctly the battery will spontaneously drop to a minimal charge current when the battery is fully charged.

Answer (score 0):

The T200 is a configurable charger with smart features.

```
Battery Types/Cells:

LiPo/LiHV/LiFe/LiIon: 1-6cells
NiMH/NiCd: 1-15cells
Pb: 2-20V

Battery Capacity Range:

NiMH/NiCd:100-50000mAh
LiPo/LiIon/LiFe/LiHV:100-50000mAh
Pb: 100-50000mAh
```

https://www.skyrc.com/t200

> Will it be okay to charge it using the program?

Yes if you use the correct configuration as directed in the manual.

[image]